# Log Analytics keep order from variable when using in()

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm kind of new to Log Analytics and I'm trying to get top 10 computers with "% Free Space" orderer by "_Total" and all disks grouped by computer ordered by "_Total" like this:

```
let top_10_free =
Perf
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space" and InstanceName == "_Total" and TimeGenerated > todatetime("2020-01-01 00:00:00")
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by Computer
| top 10 by CounterValue desc nulls last
| project Computer;
Perf
| where ObjectName == "LogicalDisk" and CounterName == "% Free Space" and Computer in(top_10_free)
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by InstanceName, Computer 
| project-rename Ultimo_Check = TimeGenerated, Instancia = Computer, Particion = InstanceName, Porcentaje_Disponible = CounterValue
| project  Ultimo_Check, Instancia, Particion, Porcentaje_Disponible
```

In this query, the computers are ordered in "top_10_free" but not in the final output.

[image: top_10_free result (with CounterValue added to project)]

The final output (this is almost what I want, except that computers aren't in the desired order):
[image: final output of the query]

To summarize, I want the group of servers of the second img (under the column of Instancia) ordered like the servers in the first img (under the column of Computer).

Expected output:

```
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|Ultimo_Check   |Instancia  |Particion  |Porcentaje_Disponible  |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |server10   |C:         |97,402                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |server10   |D:         |83,363                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |server10   |_Total     |90,383                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |server     |C:         |83,849                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |server     |D:         |91,185                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |server     |_Total     |87,617                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |AK         |C:         |67,599                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |AK         |HarddiskVol|30,461                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
|somedate       |AK         |_Total     |67,735                 |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------------+
Then AC with _Total = 66,281
Then CU with _Total = 63,249
Then CO with _Total = 37,563
Then GR with _Total = 36,19
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does adding an `order by` at the end help? for example:

```
...
| project  Ultimo_Check, Instancia, Particion, Porcentaje_Disponible
| order by Instancia asc, Porcentaje_Disponible desc
```

**Edited to add the comment that solved the issue**

`order by` orders records according to sort keys. it doesn't order "groups of records", as there's no such notion in the query language, nor in the underlying data layer. you may want to restructure your data (at query time) such that you end up with a record per "group" (e.g. have `_Total` as one column and the rest of the drives within a property bag like `{"C:":1234, "D:":3456}`. then, you could order the records (now "groups") by the column `_Total`

Comment: I tried some combinations of order by, including the one suggested by you wich doesn't prioritize the "_Total" value of a group of Instancia

Comment: you may want to clarify what your expected result is. it's currently hard to deduce that based on your current comments: "this is almost what I want, except that computers aren't in the desired order", "doesn't prioritize the "_Total" value of a group of Instancia"

Comment: added a summary and expected output

Comment: did you try including `Particion` as one of the sort keys? unless i'm misunderstanding your intention, it should sort as you expect. e.g. try running this: ```datatable(s:string)
[
    @"Z:\",
    @"C:\",
    @"D:\",
    @"_Total"
]
| order by s asc```

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding it. I'll explain it in another way: there are groups of servers, each group has its disks with free space and its `_Total`, I want to **order those group of servers** by the `_Total` value and display the groups in that same order. The main thing to be ordered is the groups, not necessarily the disks in the groups

Comment: `order by` orders records according to sort keys. it doesn't order "groups of records", as there's no such notion in the query language, nor in the underlying data layer. you may want to restructure your data (at query time) such that you end up with a record per "group" (e.g. have `_Total` as one column and the rest of the drives within a property bag like `{"C:":1234, "D:":3456}`. then, you could order the records (now "groups) by the column `_Total`